# LinkLabel.Click : InvalidCastexception on EventArgs

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In `visual studio 2010` I drag `a standard linklabel` onto  a form. I `doubleclick` the label to produce the `Click-EventHandler`.

Which produces the following result:

```
Private Sub lnkDoc_LinkClicked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles lnkDoc.Click
    Process.Start(....)
End Sub
```

When `running (no builderrors) & clicking the link` the following Error occurs:

```
JIT-Exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs'.
```

When i `change` the `eventhandler` to use the `MouseEventsArgs` instead then `i dont encouter any problems`:

```
   Private Sub lnkDoc_LinkClicked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lnkDoc.Click
        Process.Start(....)
    End Sub
```

**Question:**
Why would Visual Studio offer to use '`LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs`' instead of the needed '`MouseEventArgs`' And how can I protect myself for such errors in the future?

**Note:**

[LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabellinkclickedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx): Provides data for the LinkClicked event.

[MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) : Provides data for the MouseUp, MouseDown, and MouseMove events.

Comment: Have you noticed that you handle the click-event and not the `LinkClicked`-event?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Indeed. I didn't notice it sofar. I must have gotten to focussed on the generated function name. Now its starting to make a lot more sense;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both two different events, there is a [`Click`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.90).aspx) and a  [`LinkClicked`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkclicked(v=vs.110).aspx). In the properties box, view the events and you will see, if you want to generate a method automatically just double click in the field under the corresponding event.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkclicked(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Typically, the `LinkClicked` event is handled to perform tasks when the
>   user clicks on a link in the control. The event handler for the
>   `LinkClicked` event is passed an instance of the 
>   `LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs` class that contains a `LinkLabel.Link`
>   object that is associated with the link that was clicked. You can use
>   information specified in the LinkData property of   LinkLabel.Link
>   class to determine which link was clicked or what type of task to
>   perform when the  link is clicked. For example, if a `LinkLabel` control
>   has a `LinkLabel.Link` object defined with its  LinkData property set to
>   the string www.microsoft.com, you can use this information in an event
>   handler for the LinkClicked event to display the Web site.